# UI-bootsrap collapse doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have `angular` application with `ui-bootsrap` module. I'm trying to use `ui.bootstrap.collapse` element.

My controller:

```
function LoggerController($scope){

    $scope.isCollapsed = false;

    $scope.collapse = function(){
       $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
    }
}
```

And template:

```
<div id="footer" ng-controller="LoggerController">
        <button id="logger_button" ng-click="collapse()" class="btn">
            <i class="icon-file"></i></div>
        </button>

        <div collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="well well-large">Some content</div> 
        </div>

</div>
```

But when i'm clicking at `logger_button`, there is no any actions, `div` doesn't collapsed?

How to do it correctly?

**UPD.** Found solution. Problem was in `<i class="icon-file"></i></div>`.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo

Answer (score 2):

That's because your button is broken, it has a `</div>` inside of it, so it doesn't receive a click event at all.